# Need help identifying a vintage diode

Tags: diodes, identification

I am trying to identify this diode (D4) from a vintage synth PSU board.
The colours are green green blue. The other diode under R12 is the same.
Does anyone know what it is or an equivalent, so I can replace it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a small signal diode.  Can't say for sure, but probably something like a 1N4148.  They were jellybean parts back in the old days.

Comment: If you end up needing to match this closely (unlikely for a PSU), consider the following.  If you can remove the other diode from the board, *characterize it*.  I mean, put a 1k resistor in series with it, connect to a variable power supply, then measure both the voltage across the diode and the resistor.  Take many samples at various voltages, put that data into a spreadsheet, and plot the diode voltage against the current.  The diodes in the infamous Klon Centaur were characterized, chosen, and matched similarly.  This can also show if it is a Zener (supply in reverse) and at what voltage.

Comment: @rdtsc I'd never heard of the Kklon Centaur, had to [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klon_Centaur).  Amazing story!

Comment: What synth is it? For many of the older synths you can find the scanned service manuals online.  The board looks like a mouse peed on it based on the condition of the resistor next to it. You could try measuring the voltage across both diodes which might also give some hints.

Comment: @Kartman It is a Korg M1. Power board is KLM 1267. The board is not connected to power as I took out capacitors and other resistors, including the one in the photo.

Answer (score 8):

Korg M1 Service manual says diode D4 on KLM1267 power supply board is 1SS84.

Most photos of 1SS84 have rings with blue-green-green.

Hitachi 1SS84 data sheet says the colours are light blue for the cathode band and dark green for the 2nd and 3rd band.

Comment: BINGO! That's the correct answer. It may be hard to see on the picture, but the colors match - they're dark green as you say, not black. 1N4148 as a substitute will work fine in this application.

Answer (score 5):

Could be 1N755 7.5V Zener diodes if that first band is taken as purple.

Easy enough to pull one out and test it.